# Play & JSON: How to transform a sequence of (String, JsValue) into a JsObject

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following scala sequence...

```
val numbers = Seq[(String, JsValue)](("one", JsNumber(1)), ("two", JsNumber(2)), ("three", JsNumber(3)))
```

... I need to transform it into the following JSON:

```
{
    "numbers": {
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2,
        "three": 3
    }
}
```

I've tried this...

```
val js = Json.obj("numbers" -> Json.obj(numbers))
```

... but it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
found:       Seq[(String, JsValue)]
required:    (String, JsValueWrapper)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close enough. Use this:

```
val js = Json.obj("numbers" -> JsObject(numbers))
```

Output:

```
js: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"numbers":{"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}}
```

`Json.obj` is a shortcut to construct a `JsObject` and it is just not that convenient in your case.